# unable to send image through discord webhooks

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-imaging-library, webhooks

i created a method that takes a screenshot

```py
def send_screenshot_to_discord(self):
        webhook=discord_webhooks.DiscordWebhooks("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/xyz")
        img=ImageGrab.grab()
        webhook.set_image(image=img)
        webhook.set_footer(text="img")
        webhook.send()
```

the result :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `discord_webhooks` package you're using does not support file attachments, making it impossible to set the locally saved images or Pil-created images as embed images.

The way you set local images as embed images is by using `attachment://image.png` as the `embed.set_image` function's `url` argument, and since you cannot attach images, you can't do that.

[Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-use-a-local-image-file-for-an-embed-image) is the FAQ from `discord.py` on how to set local images as embed images.

```py
file = discord.File("path/to/my/image.png", filename="image.png")
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
await channel.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

Consider using [discord_webhook](https://pypi.org/project/discord-webhook/) or `discord.py`'s webhook.